# wxPython - change panel by button

Tags: wxpython

I would like to write simple code with 2 panels. Simple "Hello" and button next to it. Button changes panel to panel_2 with text "Panel 2" and button next to it. I do not know how can I achieve that. There is my code:

```
import wx


class Glowne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.SetSize((800,600))

        tekst = 'HELLO'
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, tekst, (300, 10)).SetFont(font)

        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Program.zmiana, btn)

 class Glowne1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        tekst = 'Panel 2'
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, tekst, (300, 10)).SetFont(font)

        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 100))
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, frame.zmiana, btn)



class Program(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,'Program')

        panel_one = Glowne(self)
        self.panel_two = Glowne1(self)
        self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.SetSize((800,600))
        self.Centre()
    def zmiana(self):
        self.panel_one.Hide()
        self.panel_two.Show()   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Program()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for any help. I read [this tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) but I can't make it work in my simple code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Program Frame needs a sizer added, the panels need self added to btn so they can be accesed from class Program, bind to the buttons inside of the class Program.

Here is an example

```
import wx


class Glowne(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.SetSize((800, 600))

        tekst = 'HELLO'
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, tekst, (300, 10)).SetFont(font)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 100))


class Glowne1(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        tekst = 'Panel 2'
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, tekst, (300, 10)).SetFont(font)

        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 100))


class Program(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Program')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.panel_one = Glowne(self)
        sizer.Add(self.panel_one, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel_one.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_panel_two)
        self.panel_two = Glowne1(self)
        sizer.Add(self.panel_two, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel_two.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.show_panel_one)
        self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.SetSize((800, 600))
        self.Centre()

    def show_panel_one(self, event):
        self.panel_one.Show()
        self.panel_two.Hide()
        self.Layout()

    def show_panel_two(self, event):
        self.panel_two.Show()
        self.panel_one.Hide()
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Program()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. Is it proper way to write programs? I mean programs with panel, program settings e.t.c?